# mobile application: how do I provide client authentication

Tags: authentication, mobile, client-server, lamp

I had an idea for a fitness mobile app and I have been developing applications based on this idea for iPhone (Obj-C based), Android (java based), WebOS (html5 based) and Nokia Qt.

I now need to provide authentication to the users of my application. The server is a typical LAMP system. I would like the users of my mobile application to log in to the server seamlessly and securely.

I am not really a web programmer and hence would appreciate ideas on how I can go about providing authentication. I've heard about OpenID...but I am not sure if it can be used for authenticating mobile clients. Some one mentioned OAuth but I am not sure if a) it would work in this use case and b) What if my client does not have a Facebook/Twitter account?

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: what language / tool-kit are you using for your LAMP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a LAMP server somewhere, it should be fairly easy to set implement your own API for password authentication -- the important thing is that you do it via HTTPS! (so the user-ids / passwords can not be sniffed). You will need a digital certificate (CERT) for your web-server.

On your LAMP system you can keep the user data in it's database. Your LAMP server should also allow to create a local user account (of course).

You can use this solution either separate or together with OpenID or OAuth!

That means, if your client doesn't have Facebook or Twitter, they can still create an account on your LAMP server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar and used gnuTLS and a x.509 certificate to authenticate from the client side. Its seamless and easy to integrate.

https://idlebox.net/2009/apidocs/gnutls-2.6.6.zip/gnutls_7.html#SEC65

The important thing about using this method for me was that the https connection was just simple method calls and the handshaking process itself would be handled by the gnuTLS library.

My app was an iOS app and i used xcode to do it which was easy. I think it will be easier on the Java side but I am not sure about the Nokia part. The coding is in C and is thus cross platform.

However if you are looking for a iOS based solution i recommend http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html

But for a cross platform solution that would require the same certificate across all applications and no input or work fro the user, I still suggest gnuTLS and using the x509 certificate.